Injection services with different lifetimes
I am learning to work with DI-container correctly and cannot understand one point. I read that I cannot inject services with smaller lifetimes into services with bigger lifetimes. For example, I shouldn't inject Scoped services into Singleton service. I cannot find information about the Transient services inside the Scoped service.
I was searching for information on StackOverflow and in the docs but couldn't find an answer. From my point of view, it's a good approach because the DI container will control the creation and disposal (if needed) of Transient services, which are created every time they are requested, aligning with the main idea of Transient lifetime. However, I want to be sure about this because I don't have extensive experience with the .NET platform.

Think about this: what is the scope if you inject a scoped service into a singleton one? In ASP.NET Core the scope is usually the web request. How can you have a web request that lasts for the life of a singleton? How might this be different to a transient in a scoped service?

Not sure if a duplicate, but I think you'll find the answer to your question here

Well, best is by testing on your own - ASP.NET app does not throw error if you try to resolve transient service for scoped service.
You could think of it that way: transient services live for as long as they are needed and it makes perfect sense, if they are needed by scoped service and live as long as the request, or needed by singleton (resolving transient service for singletons also works fine).
